# When to dispose of System.Threading.Task with child tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a task that launches several child tasks.  (e.g., Task A creates B,C,D,E,F).  I also create a `System.Threading.Timer` to poll a database every 10 seconds to check if the scheduled item was cancelled by request.  If it does, it sets `CancellationTokenSource` so that the task knows to cancel.  Each sub-task, in this case B,C,D,E,F, will cancel when appropriate (they are looping thru files and moving them around).

Since `Task` implements `IDisposable`, I want to know if it is a good idea to call `Task.WaitAll` again from the `catch` block, to wait for the cancellations to propogate.  While the cancellation request will be processed, the sub-tasks may be in the middle of a loop and can't cancel until that completes

However, per MSDN:

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Task. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Task object's Finalize method.

Should I call wait again on my task array in order to properly call `Dispose()` on each task in the array?

```
public class MyCancelObject
{
  CancellationTokenSource Source { get;set;}
  int DatabaseId { get;set;}   
}

private void CheckTaskCancelled(object state)
{
  MyCancelObject sourceToken = (MyCancelObject)state;

  if (!sourceToken.CancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    //Check database to see if cancelled -- if so, set to cancelled
    sourceToken.CancelToken.Cancel();
  }
}

private void SomeFunc()
{
  Task.StartNew( () =>
  {
    MyCancelObject myCancelObject = new MyCancelObject(
      databaseId,
      new CancellationTokenSource());
    System.Threading.Timer cancelTimer = new Timer(
      new TimerCallback(CheckIfTaskCancelled),
      myCancelObject,
      10000,
      10000);        
    Task[] someTasks = new Task[someNumberOfTasks];

    for (int i = 0; i < someNumberOfTasks; i++)
      someTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
          DoSomeWork(someObject, myCancelObject.CancelToken.Token);
        },
        TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
        myCancelObject.CancelToken.Token);

    try
    {
      Task.WaitAll(someTasks, cts);
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
      //Do stuff to handle
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      //Should I call Task.WaitAll(someTasks) again??
      //I want to be able to dispose.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested some code and found that `Task.WaitAll` can be called again to safely wait for the tasks that still might be running.  After that, they can be disposed.  I'd still like to know if there are other ways to handle this though.

Comment: It is not only acceptable to your own question, but it is encouraged. Feel free to post an answer and accept it if you feel like you have figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like I have figured this out, but anyone that would like to add anything else useful is more than welcome.

I simply called `Task.WaitAll()` again from the catch block to wait for the other tasks to finish.  After they have all finished, I have a finally block cleaning up all tasks in the array.

```
try
{
Task.WaitAll(someTaskArray, cancelToken)
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
Task.WaitAll(someTaskArray);
}
finally
{
for (int i = 0; i < someTaskArray.Length; i++)
someTaskArray[i].Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Mine feels worse than that, in order to wait I had to:
try { Tasks.WaitAll(tasks); }
catch(OperationCanceledException) {
    try { Tasks.WaitAll(tasks); }
    catch(AggregateException) { Tasks.WaitAll(tasks); }
    }
Then dispose...

Not sure why, but this seems to work.